# Are there any companies working on blockchain with clojure?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum-classic, bitcoin

Are there any commercial FinTech companies or startups are working on  blockchain technologies using the Clojure programming language?

Comment: Please guys this is stack exchange, not stack overflow. Where else should I asked this question?